# What is your name? What is your quest? What is the story behind Satellite 1963-38C?

Tags: history, identify-this-object, earth-observation, magnetosphere

[image: Kirkeland anode globe]

[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Birkeland-anode-globe-fig259.jpg) see also the page [On Possible Electric Phenomena in Solar Systems and Nebulae By Kristian Birkeland](https://www.plasma-universe.com/on-possible-electric-phenomena-in-solar-systems-and-nebulae-by-kristian_birkeland/) extracted from [The Norwegian Aurora Polaris Expedition 1902-1903 (Book)](https://www.plasma-universe.com/the-norwegian-aurora-polaris-expedition-1902-1903-book/)

---

Wikipedia's [Birkeland current; History](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birkeland_current#History) says

> Proof of Birkeland's theory of the aurora only came after a probe was sent into space. The crucial results were obtained from **U.S. Navy satellite 1963-38C**, launched in 1963 and carrying a magnetometer above the ionosphere. In 1966 Alfred Zmuda, J.H. Martin, and F.T.Heuring [16](https://agupubs.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1029/JZ071i021p05033) analysed the satellite magnetometer results and reported their findings of magnetic disturbance in the aurora.

Everywhere I look this spacecraft is called only satellite 1963-38C!

- "**Satellite 1963 38C**" Amazon E-book: [Satellite 1963 38C Semiannual report, period ending Sep. 30, 1965 Kindle Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07XTJLYBG):
- "**polar orbiting satellite 1963 38C**" [old papers](https://www.jhuapl.edu/Content/techdigest/pdf/V07-N04/07-04-Cited.pdf), [Nightside Magnetosphere Configuration as Obtained from Trapped Electrons at 1100 Kilometers](https://agupubs.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1029/JZ070i013p03017)
- "**polar orbiting satellite 1963 38C**" [old reports](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.883.9502&rep=rep1&type=pdf):  "Technical Memorandum JHAPL Radiation Damage to Orbiting Solar Cells and Transistors"
- "**magnetically oriented satellite 1963 38C**" [Transverse magnetic disturbances at 1100 kilometers in the auroral region](https://agupubs.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1029/JZ071i021p05033):
- "**1963 38C**" NASA TM-X-63121: [Observations of trapped electrons at low and high altitudes by 1963 38C satellite and Explorer 26 satellite](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/citations/19680008713)

I only found one thing that suggests the name for it. In the Johns Hopkins Applied Physics Laboratory 1968 report [Summary of APL Satellites](https://www.jhuapl.edu/Content/techdigest/pdf/APL-V07-N04/APL-07-04-Satellites.pdf) Volume 7, No. 4., there is gantt-chart-like Figure 2 which includes

```
1968-38B    5BN-1
1968-38C    5E-1
```

which I assume are APL internal codes for the spacecraft.

[image]

> Fig. 2 - Operational Status History of the 36 Satellites Fabricated at APL.

**Question:** What is your name? What is your quest? What is the story behind Satellite 1963-38C? Did the spacecraft have a people-friendly name? Or a project codename that's since been declassified? Did it have a stated mission goal at the time?

Comment: +1 for the Old Man From Scene 24 reference.

Comment: -0 for the same.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It was a secondary payload [launched along with the first operational Transit navigation satellite](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Observation_of_the_Earth_and_Its_Environ/T2W-DwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=transit%20secondary%20payload%20september%201963&pg=PA792&printsec=frontcover) (Transit 5BN-1) and was named, mundanely enough, Transit 5E-1.

Mission goals were

> - Measure omnidirectional flux of protons and electrons above certain threshold energies in order to determine the temporal variations in the radiation environment.
> - Verify information pertinent to radiation effects on various transistors.
> - Determine the effectiveness of seven selected thermal coatings.
> - Determine the effectiveness of protective coatings on solar cells in preventing degradation due to radiation.
> - Backup Satellite Transit-5BN-1 Objective to increase knowledge of the earth's shape and gravitational field.

[image]

> Satellite 5E-1 has become one of the most productive satellites ever launched. Data were acquired routinely for over six years and the satellite has functioned for a full solar cycle (11 years).

Source [Gunter's Space Page](https://space.skyrocket.de/doc_sdat/transit-5e1.htm)

The source document : [Artificial Earth Satellites Designed And Fabricated By The Johns Hopkins University Applied Physics Laboratory](http://www.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/a066299.pdf) may also be of interest. The following diagram came from it.

[image]

Comment: It continues to amaze me how quick and spot-on your answers are.

Comment: @OrganicMarble Have you ever considered doing a presentation of sorts about your experiences?  Would love to hear more about things that we don't know to ask about.

Comment: @Brad There's a website listed in my stack exchange user profile on which I blather on about stuff I did.